# optimal screen idle timeout

Tags: login, timeout

Is there any research studying the optimal screen idle timeout, balancing convenience to the user versus security? In the scenario I'm considering, a timeout causes the user to have to log in again.

Comment: Hello Al Lelopath. This question has actually been asked and answered before. Take a look at the answers on the question I linked; if they do not answer your question completely, consider [edit]ing your question to clarify any other issues you may be concerned about. One thing I will underscore is that the user should be notified before they are automatically logged out, and given the opportunity to take action to prevent the log out.

Comment: That question does mostly answer my question. The only additional thing i was seeking as some research, some objective data, the supports how to make decisions for this, but maybe that doesn't exist.